# How to create a tweak for ios 6?

Tags: ios, ios6

I am new here and I would like to learn how to make a tweak for iOS 6 to change the navigation bars text color and the navigation bar back buttons text color to make them look like in iOS 7.I don't have objective c knowledge and i want to learn really want to make this tweak so,can you give me some help with tutorials,code or something else?

sorry bad english

Thanks

Comment: Since you are new, it would help if you became familiar with the [rules for question asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's not really the place to ask for tutorials. If you don't know Objective-C then use a search engine to find a tutorial. You could check this : http://courseware.codeschool.com/try_ios/objective_c_primer.pdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you have a full wiki with info about **iPhone** and **iOS** development:

[iPhoneDev Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Getting_Started)

And here two basics tutorials about creating a **sample tweak** for iOS:

[Tutorial 1](http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-your-first-tweak)

[Tutorial 2](http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/10096812242/jailbroken-development-making-a-basic-tweak)